# Airflow Tasks are not getting triggered

Tags: scheduler, airflow

I am scheduling the dag and it shows in the running state but tasks are not getting triggered.Airflow scheduler and web server are up and running. I toggled the dag as ON on the UI. Still i cant able to fix the issue.I am using CeleryExecutor tried changing to the SequentialExecutor but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the CeleryExecutor you have to start the airflow workers too.
cmd: `airflow worker`

You need the following commands:

```
airflow worker
airflow scheduler
airflow webserver
```

If it still doesn't probably you have set `start_date: datetime.today()`.